# Solving Series of a Sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

Hey Guys I was wondering if I could get some help in solving a series.
$$\sum_{n={0}}^\infty\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}(\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}$$
How would I go on about and solve this series? If I could get an explanation I would greatly appreciate it and one more thing the use for this function is used for the calculation for a solera method where $n$ is the amount of years the solera has been going and $k$ is the number of tiers where in the example I am doing there is only 5 tiers, so it will always be $k=5$.

Comment: Can you explain the values of your index?

Comment: Don't you recognize the Binomial formula ?

Comment: You do not solve  a series. You evaluate a  series. You solve a problem. The problem to solve is how to  evaluate the series.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: for $|x| \lt 1$,

$$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \binom{n-1}{k-1} x^{n-k} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k-1}{k-1} x^n = (1-x)^{-k}$$

Comment: Because if you integrate the middle term and the far-right term $k-1$ times you get ,respectively, the series for $ f(x)=(-1)^{k-1} (1-x)^{-1}/(k-1)!$ and the  function $f(x)$ itself...............+1